# Azure Blob Storage DownloadToStreamAsync hangs during network change

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I've been having an issue with the [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage v9.3.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) and [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob v11.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/) NuGet libraries. Specifically when download a large file. If you change your network during the "DownloadToStreamAsync" method the call hangs. I've been seeing my code, which processes a *lot* of files, hang occasionally and I've been trying to narrow it down. I think the network change might be a reliable way of triggering some failure in the Azure Blob Storage Libraries.

More info about the issue;

- When I unplug my network cable my computer switches to WiFi but the request never resumes
- If I start the download on WiFi and then plug in my network cable the same error occurs
- The “ServerTimeout” property never fails the request or acts as expected in accordance to the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions?view=azure-dotnet)
- The “MaximumExecutionTime” property does fail the request but we don’t want to limit ourselves to a certain time period, especially because we’re dealing with large files

The following code fails 100% of the time if the network is changed during the call.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        CloudStorageAccount.TryParse("<Connection String>", out var storageAccount);
        var cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("<Container Reference>");
        var blobRef = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Large Text.txt");
        Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        BlobRequestOptions optionsWithRetryPolicy = new BlobRequestOptions() { ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), 4) };
        blobRef.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream, null, optionsWithRetryPolicy, null).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("Completed");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    }
}
```

I've found [this active issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/790) in the Azure Storage GitHub but it seems inactive.

Is there any other approach I could take to reliably and efficiently download a blob or something I'm missing when using this package?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post now. I wondered if there was anything else I could be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mohit for the suggestion.

- Create a Task to check the stream length in the background
- If the stream hasn't increased in a set period of time, cancel the DownloadToStreamAsync

DISCLAIMER: I haven't written tests around this code or how to make it run in a performant way as you couldn't have a wait like this for every file you process. I might need to cancel the initial task if the download completes, I don't know yet, I just wanted to get it working first. I don't deem it production ready.

```
// Create download cancellation token
var downloadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var downloadCancellationToken = downloadCancellationTokenSource.Token;

var completedChecking = false;

// A background task to confirm the download is still progressing
Task.Run(() =>
{
    // Allow the download to start
    Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    long currentStreamLength = 0;
    var currentRetryCount = 0;
    var availableRetryCount = 5;

    // Keep the checking going during the duration of the Download
    while (!completedChecking)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Checking");
        if (currentRetryCount == availableRetryCount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"RETRY WAS {availableRetryCount} - FAILING TASK");
            downloadCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            completedChecking = true;
        }

        if (currentStreamLength == memoryStream.Length)
        {
            currentRetryCount++;
            Console.WriteLine($"Length has not increased. Incremented Count: {currentRetryCount}");
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        else
        {
            currentStreamLength = memoryStream.Length;
            Console.WriteLine($"Download in progress: {currentStreamLength}");
            currentRetryCount = 0;
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
});

Console.WriteLine("Starting Download");

blobRef.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream, downloadCancellationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Console.WriteLine("Completed Download");
completedChecking = true;

Console.WriteLine("Completed");
```